# How might I diagnose whether I have a working ethernet interface?

Tags: network-interface, ethernet

I bought a [laptop this year](https://www.gigabyte.com/eu/Laptop/AERO-17--RTX-30-Series/sp#sp), not via this website but from a vendor on Amazon.
I cannot connect to the internet via cable
and I'm afraid that my network interface is not working correctly for some unknown to me reason.

My environment: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS (the problem was present on Windows as well -
the OS that laptop was shipped to me). I can connect through the same cable from another laptop. WiFi works on this laptop but the quality is not good.

I ran `ip l` to identify the name of the interface in question and got the following output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:0f:14:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group
```

I've trimmed the last line of the output in order to avoid doxing the details of my wireless interface.
Having identified the name of the interface in question as `enp3s0` I then proceeded further with my investigation and ran

```
sudo ethtool enp3s0
```

which returned the following output (irrespectively of the cable being plugged in or not).

```
Settings for enp3s0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: no
```

I've tried also `sudo ethtool -p enp3s0 15`
and got the following output (irrespectively of the cable being plugged in or not):

```
Cannot identify NIC: Operation not supported
```

The output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` is:

```
NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
NVRM: BAR0 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:01:00.0)
nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
NVRM: BAR0 is 0M @ 0x0 (PCI:0000:01:00.0)
[...]
nvidia: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -1
NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
```

Where `[...]` stands for the first seven lines of the output repeated over 300 times.

My question is **do I have a working ethernet interface?**

Comment: Look at `sudo lshw -C network`. Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man lshw journalctl`.

Comment: You might have a network interface that uses a very new driver, or the driver has a poor `ethtool` support for some reason. Please run `sudo ethtool -i enp3s0`: it will identify the driver used for the network interface, and the NIC firmware version, if applicable.

Comment: Please edit your question and add `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` output.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've just noticed your last comment. I've already added the output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` to my question in response to your comment. Apologies for being so inattentive and for responding so late. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Link detected: no
```

and

> the problem was present on Windows as well - the OS that that laptop was shipped to me

Strongly indicate your NIC is not working. The circuitry might be OK, but a pin/some pins could be broken.

You're good to RMA the laptop or replace the NIC/connector.

Comment: the question states *the problem was present on Windows as well* - so, I'm guessing *even Windows fails to initialize network on this interface* :p

Comment: Sorry, was inattentive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications of the laptop, the wired NIC is a Realtek RTL8125-BG. It needs a firmware file to work correctly.

Looks like there are multiple versions of the NIC hardware, requiring different firmware files. The [linux-firmware package in the main Ubuntu 20.04 repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/linux-firmware) seems to only include the `rtl8125a-3.fw` version of the firmware. You might need the [package version available in the `focal-updates` repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/linux-firmware) which also includes the `rtl8125b-1.fw` and `rtl8125b-2.fw` firmware files.

You should check that the later two firmware files are present on your system in the `/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/` directory, and if they aren't there, enable the `focal-updates` repository and update the `linux-firmware` package.

The support for RTL8125 version B was [added into the kernel in July 2020](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek?h=v5.14.21&id=0439297be95111cf9ef5ece2091af16d140ce2ef). If you are running the 20.04 default kernel version (5.4 series), you might also need to install the newer "hardware enablement kernel" (5.8 series) to make your RTL8125 version B work correctly.

Although [the Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS should have received the hardware enablement kernel automatically](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/improvements-for-hardware-support-in-ubuntu-desktop-installation-media/20606), it's better to check than guess. Please run `uname -r`: it reports the version number of the current kernel. If it's 5.4.*something*, you might be missing some updates.

Comment: `rtl8125b-*.fw` are present. My kernel version is 5.11.0-41-generic. I cannot find **hardware enablement kernel** with `apt search`. Does this package have a different name?

Comment: The fact that you have received the `5.11.*` kernel indicates you already have the hardware enablement updates. Perhaps Realtek has made yet another hardware revision of the NIC and the yours is unfortunately not quite supported yet. Or perhaps the NIC has a hardware fault. What does `lspci -nn -d ::0200` report? The exact PCI ID number and revision might be important.

Comment: `lspci -nn -d ::0200` gives me `03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)`