# Having downloaded keyring and imported public key, why is the public key still unavailable for apt?

Tags: apt, gpg, key-authentication

I am trying to install `brave-browser-beta` on [Debian testing](https://www.debian.org/releases/) with the following script run as `root`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdir=$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")
skf="${pdir}/brave-beta-signing-key"

gpg --import "$skf"
  

brave-beta() {
  curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg
  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com/ stable main">/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-beta.list
  apt update && apt install -y brave-browser-beta
}      

brave-beta
```

where `brave-beta-signing-key` is a file with the public key copied and pasted from the [brave.com](https://brave.com/signing-keys/#packages-beta-channel). The script does nothing less but [following the official instructions
of installing the browser](https://brave.com/linux/#beta-channel-installation).
I get the following output:

```
gpg: key 0B31DBA06A8A26F9: public key "Brave Software (Brave Core Nightly Key) (We're reinventing the browser as a user-first platform for speed and privacy.) <support@brave.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian trixie InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security trixie-security InRelease     
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian trixie-updates InRelease                    
Get:4 https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [7547 B]    
Err:4 https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease    
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[The research](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/35657) I've done includes `m̀an apt-secure`:

> 

```
   The chain of trust in Debian starts (e.g.) when a maintainer uploads a
   new package or a new version of a package to the Debian archive. In
   order to become effective, this upload needs to be signed by a key
   contained in one of the Debian package maintainer keyrings (available
   in the debian-keyring package). Maintainers' keys are signed by other
   maintainers following pre-established procedures to ensure the identity
   of the key holder. Similar procedures exist in all Debian-based
   distributions.
```

I had [`debian-archive-keyring`](https://packages.debian.org/source/trixie/debian-archive-keyring), but not [`debian-keyring`](https://packages.debian.org/source/trixie/debian-keyring) pre-installed. I then have installed `debian-keyring`
but to no avail.
I've imported the very same key and have the required keyring in `/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg` as confirmed by `ls -l`,
`-rw------- 1 root root 2.5K Jan 27 13:01 /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg`.
Why do I then get from `apt`: `GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-beta.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0B31DBA06A8A26F9` ?
I had the same problem some time ago on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I could successfully install `brave-browser-beta` on [Antix](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=antix) without the need of importing the signing key, though.

Comment: Instead of the `curl`, try `cp "$skf" /usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-beta-archive-keyring.gpg`

Comment: @muru Sadly, it has not helped - I still get the same message.

Comment: Why are you importing the key?  All the curl command is doing is copying the key from the website into the directory.  Have you installed per the directions you linked without the script?

Comment: @eyoung100 I thought about importing it because of the output I get from `apt`. I could not manually install without the script either but only on one laptop that I know has a faulty networking card as i described it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681286/how-might-i-diagnose-whether-i-have-a-working-ethernet-interface

Answer (score 0):

I cannot install `brave-browser` nor `brave-browser-beta` but only on one laptop that I know has a faulty networking card as I [described it here some time ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/681286/how-might-i-diagnose-whether-i-have-a-working-ethernet-interface). The issue is not present on any other of my computers.